# Pattern Matching tuples in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Trying to get a handle on pattern matching here-- coming from a C++/Java background it's very foreign to me.

The point of this branch is to check each member of a List `d` of tuples [format of (string,object). I want to define three cases.

1) If the counter in this function is larger than the size of the list (defined in another called acc), I want to return nothing (because there is no match)
2) If the `key` given in the input matches a tuple in the list, I want to return its value (or, whatever is stored in the tuple._2). 
3) If there is no match, and there is still more list to iterate, increment and continue.

My code is below:

```
def get(key:String):Option[Any] = {

        var counter: Int = 0
        val flag: Boolean = false 

        x match {

                case (counter > acc) => None

                case ((d(counter)._1) == key) => d(counter)._2

                case _ =>   counter += 1
                }
```

My issue here is while the first case seems to compile correctly, the second throws an error:

```
:36: error: ')' expected but '.' found.
                case ((d(counter)._1) == key) => d(counter)._2
```

The third as well:

```
scala>         case _ =>  counter += 1
:1: error: illegal start of definition
```

But I assume it's because the second isn't correct. My first thought is that I'm not comparing tuples correctly, but I seem to be following the syntax for indexing into a tuple, so I'm stumped. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: What is `x`?  What is `d`?  To have a condition in a match statement you need `case` (variable name or pattern to match) `if` (condition) `=>` (what you should do or return).

Comment: Looks like your `d` doesn't return a tuple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully a few things to clear up your confusion:

Matching in scala follows this general template:

```
x match {
  case SomethingThatXIs if(SomeCondition) => SomeExpression
  // rinse and repeat
  // note that `if(SomeCondition)` is optional
}
```

It looks like you may have attempted to use the match/case expression as more of an if/else if/else kind of block, and as far as I can tell, the `x` doesn't really matter within said block. If that's the case, you might be fine with something like

```
case _ if (d(counter)._1 == key) => d(counter)._2
```

**BUT**

Some info on `List`s in scala. You should always think of it like a `LinkedList`, where indexed lookup is an `O(n)` operation. Lists can be matched with a `head :: tail` format, and `Nil` is an empty list. For example:

```
val myList = List(1,2,3,4)
myList match {
  case first :: theRest => 
    // first is 1, theRest is List(2,3,4), which you can also express as
    // 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil
  case Nil =>
    // an empty list case
}
```

It looks like you're constructing a kind of ListMap, so I'll write up a more "functional"/"recursive" way of implementing your `get` method.

I'll assume that `d` is the backing list, of type `List[(String, Any)]`

```
def get(key: String): Option[Any] = {
  def recurse(key: String, list: List[(String, Any)]): Option[Any] = list match {
    case (k, value) :: _ if (key == k) => Some(value)
    case _ :: theRest => recurse(key, theRest)
    case Nil => None
  }
  recurse(key, d)
}
```

The three case statements can be explained as follows:

1) The first element in `list` is a tuple of `(k, value)`. The rest of the list is matched to the `_` because we don't care about it in this case. The condition asks if `k` is equal to the key we are looking for. In this case, we want to return the `value` from the tuple.

2) Since the first element didn't have the right key, we want to recurse. We don't care about the first element, but we want the rest of the list so that we can recurse with it.

3) `case Nil` means there's nothing in the list, which should mark "failure" and the end of the recursion. In this case we return `None`. Consider this the same as your `counter > acc` condition from your question.

Please don't hesitate to ask for further explanation; and if I've accidentally made a mistake (won't compile, etc), point it out and I will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that conditionally extracting part of a tuple from a list of tuples is the important part of your question, excuse me if I'm wrong.

First an initial point, in Scala we normally would use AnyRef instead of Object or, if worthwhile, we would use a type parameter which can increase reuse of the function or method and increase type safety.

The three cases you describe can be collapsed into two cases, the first case uses a guard (the if statement after the pattern match), the second case matches the entire non-empty list and searches for a match between each first tuple argument and the key, returning a Some[T] containing the second tuple argument of the matching tuple or None if no match occurred. The third case is not required as the find operation traverses (iterates over) the list.

The map operation after the find is used to extract the second tuple argument (map on an Option returns an Option), remove this operation and change the method's return type to Option[(String, T)] if you want the whole tuple returned.

```
def f[T](key: String, xs: List[(String, T)], initialCount: Int = 2): Option[T] = {
  var counter = initialCount

  xs match {
    case l: List[(String, T)] if l.size < counter => None
    case l: List[(String, T)] => l find {_._1 == key} map {_._2}
  }
}

f("A", List(("A", 1), ("B", 2))) // Returns Some(1)
f("B", List(("A", 1), ("B", 2))) // Returns Some(2)
f("A", List(("A", 1)))           // Returns None
f("C", List(("A", 1), ("B", 2))) // Returns None
f("C", Nil)                      // Returns None
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using a `List` for that reason? What you need is definitely a `Map`. Its `get()` returns `None` if key  is  not found  and `Some(value)` if it is found in it.

Second, what is `x` in your example? Is it the list?

Third, you cannot write `case (log) => ..` where `log` is a logical condition, it is in the form of `case _ if (log) => ...` (as Rex Kerr already pinted out in his comment).

Fouth, you need a recursive function for this (simply increasing the counter will call this only on the second element).

So you'll need something like this (if still prefer sticking to `List`):

```
def get(l: List[Tuple2[String, String]], key: String): Option[String] = {
    if (l.isEmpty) {
        None
    } else {
        val act = l.head
        act match {
            case x if (act._1 == key) => Some(act._2)
            case _ => get(l.tail, key)
        }
    }
}
```